# How to find same element from item grid using loop in java selenium?

Tags: java, loops, selenium, element

I am trying to find button add to cart is present or not using loop from all item box from following code

```
<div class="page-body">
<div class="product-selectors">
<div class="product-filters-wrapper">
<div class="product-grid">
<div class="item-box">
<div class="item-box">
<div class="item-box">
<div class="item-box">
</div>
```

in each item box folowing code

```
<div class="item-box">
<div class="product-item" data-productid="20">
<div class="picture">
<div class="details">
   <h2 class="product-title">
   <div class="product-rating-box" title="1 review(s)">
      <div class="description"> 12x optical zoom; SuperRange Optical Image Stabilizer </div>
      <div class="add-info">
         <div class="prices">
            <div class="buttons">
               <input class="button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button" type="button" onclick="AjaxCart.addproducttocart_catalog('/addproducttocart/catalog/20/1/1 ');return false;" value="Add to cart">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to find that all itembox have add to cart button present or not using loop. if anyone can help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to avoid looping if not necessary. You do not need to do the loop to find out unless there is an explicit need of doing so. You can find the count of *Add to cart button* and compare with a known value

```
By byCss = By.cssSelector(".item-box>div input[value='Add to cart']");
int cartCount = driver.findElements(byCss).size();

if (cartCount != 4){
    //fail the test
}
```

If you exactly one to looping and check if the input button exist or not.

```
By itemBoxes = By.className("item-box");
By button = By.cssSelector("[type='button'][value='Add to cart']");

List<WebElement> webElementList = driver.findElements(itemBoxes);
for (WebElement element: webElementList){
    //simply taking size if exist it will return 1
    if (element.findElements(button).size() != 1){
        //fail
    }
}
```

Comment: Did that do any help?

Comment: thanks this code works perfect but i need to print product-titel which do not have add to cart button

Comment: and from each four item box its cheking if can't find from one item box it should fail test

Comment: Yes, that's what I think

Answer (score 0):

you can use searching by xpath inside of the loop.

Something like

```
".//input[@value='Add to cart'][1]"
".//input[@value='Add to cart'][2]"
".//input[@value='Add to cart'][3]"
etc
```

not sure that this xpath is correct, but generally it will work for you, bro.
Or something like this:

```
string xpath=".//input[@value='Add to cart']";

var AddToCartBtnsList = driver.findElements(By.Xpath(xpath));

foreach(IWebElement button in AddToCartBtnsList )
{
    button.click();
}
```